# MySQL Create Trigger Syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, triggers

```
DELIMITER // 
CREATE TRIGGER never_update_with_null
BEFORE UPDATE
ON `table_name`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF OLD.name IS NOT NULL AND NEW.name IS NULL THEN
        SET NEW.name = OLD.name;
    IF OLD.phone IS NOT NULL AND NEW.name IS NULL THEN
        SET NEW.phone = OLD.phone;
    IF OLD.place IS NOT NULL AND NEW.place IS NULL THEN
        SET NEW.place = OLD.place;
END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

I am trying to achieve the following:
If someone `UPDATE`s a value in `name`, `phone` or `place`(columns) in the table `table_name` and its value (the updating value) is `NULL` then the value stays the old one (does not get updated).
Maybe a little shorter: never update with NULL.

The above SQL does not create a trigger but it either does not throw any error(phpMyAdmin). Does it lack syntax? Already tried it with `ENDIF;` after every `OLD.column;` - no improvement. Thank you for explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
DELIMITER // 
CREATE TRIGGER never_update_with_null
BEFORE UPDATE
ON `table_name`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF OLD.name IS NOT NULL AND NEW.name IS NULL THEN
        SET NEW.name = OLD.name;
    END IF;
    IF OLD.phone IS NOT NULL AND NEW.phone IS NULL THEN
        SET NEW.phone = OLD.phone;
    END IF;
    IF OLD.place IS NOT NULL AND NEW.place IS NULL THEN
        SET NEW.place = OLD.place;
    END IF;
END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: sorry for inconsistency, fixed it. see Question. ty